# unevenly centered subplots in matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am plotting a simple pair of subplots in matplotlib that are for some reason unevenly centered. I plot them as follows:

```
plt.figure()
# first subplot
s1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# second subplot
s2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.pcolor(rand(5,5))

# add colorbar
plt.colorbar()

# square axes
axes_square(s1)
axes_square(s2)
```

where axes_square is simply:

```
def axes_square(plot_handle):
  plot_handle.axes.set_aspect(1/plot_handle.axes.get_data_ratio())
```

The plot I get is attached.  The top and bottom plots are unevenly centered.  I'd like their yaxis to be aligned and their boxes to be aligned.

If I remove the plt.colorbar() call, the plots become centered.  How can I have the plots centered while the colorbar of pcolor is still shown?  I want the axes to be centered and have the colorbar be outside of that alignment, either to the left or to the right of the pcolor matrix.

[image of plots link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2i1kvtu&s=6)

[image: Image of uncentered subplots in matplotlib]

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this probably isn't exactly what you want, but it'll work:

```
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
# first subplot
s1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# second subplot
s2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.pcolor(rand(5,5))

# square axes
axes_square(s1)
axes_square(s2)

s_fake = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
s_fake.set_axis_off()
# add colorbar
plt.colorbar()
```

It just makes a fake pair of cells on the left, and doesn't display anything in them. Not pretty, but it works. `;)`

Also, I'm guessing that those two imports were implicit in your code ...

Comment: thanks.  Is there a way to do this without introducing more subplots?  I am not sure why the extra subplot trick works?  There should be a way to center them without... this sounds like a bug in "colorbar()" function.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `cax` argument to colorbar to designate where you like the colorbar:

```
plt.colorbar(cax=plt.gcf().add_axes((0.75,0.1,0.05,0.3)))
```

Comment: when I do that, it erases my manual setting of x and y ticklabels on the pcolor matrix and I am also unsure how to set add_axes.  How do you determine the right coordinates to pass it?

Is there an easier way to get the colorbar to not interfere with the alignment of the plots if I place it horizontally rather than vertically? 

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any changes to tick labels. Did you post your full code?